# How to merge two hashes with no new keys

Tags: ruby, hash, key, duplicates

How could I merge two hashes that results in no new keys, meaning the merge would merge keys that exist in both hashes?

For example, I want the following:

```
h = {:foo => "bar"}
j = {:foo => "baz", :extra => "value"}

puts h.merge(j)    # {:foo => "baz"}
```

I'm looking for a really clean way of doing this as my current implementation is pretty messy.

Comment: This is like a hash intersection. What do you want to happen with key/value pairs with different values? For example: h = {:foo => "value1"}; j={:foo=>"value2", :extra=>"value"}

Comment: @Ron Gejman - I just want to throw them out. But you have sparked my interest. Is there some hash/enumerable method that would return two hashes (one with the duplicate keys and another with the leftovers)?

Comment: No, but it's easy to get using something along the lines of DigitalRoss's answer. Just save to two different hashes—one for matches and one for non-matches.

Comment: Based on your accepted answer, it sounds like you don't want intersection, but you want the resulting hash to have exactly the same keys as the first hash "h", but with values updated from the second hash "j".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could remove keys that weren't in the first hash from the second hash, then merge:

```
h.merge j.select { |k| h.keys.include? k }
```

Unlike my edited-out alternative, this is safe if you decide to change it to a `merge!` or `update`.

Comment: (removed my downvote, and changed it to an upvote. I got confused about `merge`)

Comment: This gives a warning on my machine—Hash.select takes in a block with two arguments (|k,v|).

Comment: Oh, whoops, I write Ruby 1.9.

Comment: See my answer re Hash#select in 1.8.x vs. 1.9.x.

Comment: Very clean solution. Thank you yjerem.

Comment: @elmt, @yjerem, @ron-gejman Note that `h.keys.include?(k)` is the same as `h.key?(k)` but the latter should perform better because it avoids the linear search of the `keys` array.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using activesupport (part of rails), you can take advantage of 2 extra methods on `Hash`:

- `Hash#slice` takes the desired keys as separate arguments (not an array of keys) and returns a new hash with just the keys you asked for.
- `Hash#except` takes the same arguments as `slice`, but returns a new hash with keys that were not in the arguments.

First load activesupport:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
```

Merge only entries from `j` whose keys are already in `h` (i.e. modify, but don't add any or remove entries in `h`):

```
h.merge(j.slice(*h.keys))
```

Example:

```
ignore_new = ->(h, j) { h.merge(j.slice(* h.keys)) }
ignore_new.({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {b: 10, c: 11, d: 12})
# => {:a=>1, :b=>10, :c=>11}
```

Get the leftovers from `j` that weren't in `h`:

```
j.except(*h.keys)
```

**Bonus:**

If you want true intersection, meaning you want a result that only has keys that are in common between the 2 hashes, do this:

```
h.merge(j).slice(* ( h.keys & j.keys ) )
```

Example:

```
intersect = ->(h, j) { h.merge(j).slice(* (h.keys & j.keys) ) }
intersect.({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {b: 10, c: 11, d: 12})
# => {:b=>10, :c=>11}
```

and leftovers from `h` that weren't in `j`:

```
h.except(*j.keys)
```

You may also want to use activesupport's `HashWithIndifferentAccess` if you want string & symbol key-access to be considered equivalent.

Note that none of the above examples change the original hashes; new hashes are returned instead.

Answer (score 8):

Yjerem's answer works in Ruby 1.9, but not in 1.8.x. In 1.8.x the `Hash#select` method returns an array. `Hash#reject` returns a hash.

```
h.reject { |k,v| !j.keys.include? k }
```

If you want to keep only key-value pairs that have identical values, you can do this:

```
h.reject { |k,v| j[k] != h[k] }
```

The edge case there is nils. If you are storing nils in your Hash then you have to do this:

```
h.reject { |k,v| !j.has_key? k or j[k] != h[k] }
```

Comment: Yep. It's forward compatible with 1.9 too.

Answer (score 0):

```
[h].inject({}) { |m,e| e.merge(j) { |k,o,n| m[k] = n }; m}
```

*or*

```
[{}].inject(h) { |m,e| m.merge(j) { |k,o,n| e[k] = n }; e}
```

*or* (probably the best, but not technically a single expression) ...

```
t = {}; h.merge(j) { |k,o,n| t[k] = n }; t
```

Answer (score -1):

The more customized  way of doing this is:

```
 h = {"foo"=> "bar"}

 j = {"foo" => "baz", "extra" => "value"}


 k = h.merge(j)
result:  {"foo"=>"baz", "extra"=>"value"}
```

Here the key "foo" in the second hash is overriding the "foo" in first hash.But if you want to keep the old value i.e bar or if you want keep the new value i.e "baz"?  You can do something like this:

```
  k = h.merge(j){|key, old, new| old}
 result: {"foo"=>"bar", "extra"=>"value"}


k = h.merge(j){|key, old, new| new}

result: {"foo"=>"baz", "extra"=>"value"}
```

Comment: The question asks for an intersection of the keys. The result should be {:foo => "baz"}, not {"foo"=>"baz", "extra"=>"value"}