# How do I compare hashes and output duplicates?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have three hashes, and want to output the keys that are common to them:

```
hash1 = {a: "3", b: "2" c: "1"}
hash2 = {b: "2" c: "1"}
hash3 = {b: "2" c: "1", d: "4"}
```

For the example above, the common keys would be `b` and `c`.

I need to scale this to many hashes. What is the most efficient and scalable way to do this?

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825069/merge-two-ruby-hashes-with-no-new-keys

Comment: thanks - but would that scale to more than 3 hashes?

Comment: BTW, your code is invalid. Make sure you post valid code, it can mean a difference between having lots of answer and not having any.

Answer (score 3):

```
> hashes = [{a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 5, c: 6}, {a: 6, d: 2}]
=> [{:a=>3, :b=>4}, {:a=>5, :c=>6}, {:a=>6, :d=>2}]
> hashes.map(&:keys).inject { |shared, keys| shared & keys }
=> [:a]
```

Comment: This needs some explanation.

Comment: Actually, it's shorter: `hashes.map(&:keys).inject(:&)`

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, you need something like `Hash#intersect`. Fortunately, it's trivial to implement.

```
class Hash
  def & another
    result = {}
    self.each do |k, v|
      result[k] = v if another[k] == v
    end
    result
  end
end

hash1 = {a: "3", b: "2", c: "1"}
hash2 = {b: "2", c: "1"}
hash3 = {b: "2", c: "1", d: "4"}

hashes = [hash1, hash2, hash3]


hashes.reduce(:&) # => {:b=>"2", :c=>"1"}
```

**Note:** This code assumes that keys **and** their corresponding values have to match in order to pass the filter. If you're interested in only keys themselves, it's very easy to modify the code to do that. I'll leave it up to you.