# add contents of 1 hash into another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a parent hash which changes and I want to ensure that the child hashes take these changes but also retain keys that they had before and those should not be lost

These are the sample hashes that I have

```
one = {"endpoints"=>["get_route"], "features"=>["channel_selection"], "get_route"=>{"output"=>["total_length", "seca_length"], "options"=>["panama", "abcd"]}}

other = {"endpoints"=>["get_route"], "features"=>["channel_selection"], "get_route"=>{"output"=>["total_length", "seca_length"], "options"=>["panama", "suez", "kiel"]}}
```

I want the other hash to now look like

```
other = {"endpoints"=>["get_route"], "features"=>["channel_selection"], "get_route"=>{"output"=>["total_length", "seca_length"], "options"=>["panama", "abcd", suez", "kiel"]}}
```

I have tried the following code but it is not working

```
result = propogate_changes(one, other)

def propogate_changes(one, other)
    one_keys = one.keys
    other_keys = other.keys
    combined = Hash.new
    unique_keys = one_keys.concat(other_keys).uniq

    unique_keys.each do |key|
        if(one[key].is_a?(Array)) then
            # if(other[key] == nil) then
            #     combined[key] = one[key]
            # else
                combined[key] = one[key].concat(other[key]).uniq
            # end
        else
            combined[key] = add_allowance(one[key], other[key])
        end
    end
    return combined
end
```

The above code fails when a key is present in one but missing in another

I also tried `merge, deep_merge, reverse_merge` but they all overwrite my other hash with one hash but none of them retain the original data.

Any advise on this will be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge Ruby hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415240/how-to-merge-ruby-hashes)

Comment: This is a touch unclear at the moment - which one of the example hashes is the one you refer to as 'parent', and which child? Also, what does your desired output look like?

Comment: want to update other hash with the one hash.. i tried merge, deep_merge but they all overwrite the existing hash which is not what I want.. I want to preserver the old values and just add the missing values

Comment: you can use the slice method to get the keys that are in other hash from one hash and merge it with other like, `other.merge(one.slice(*other.keys))
` here is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6074412/5934752

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this custom merge logic.

```
def find_missing_items_in_arr(arr1, arr2)
  arr1_size = arr1.size
  arr2_size = arr2.size

  if (arr1_size == arr2_size) && (arr1 & arr2).size == arr1_size
    return [] # Same array
  end

  arr2 - arr1
end

def custom_merge(target_hash, source_hash)
  # If you want to preserve frozen state of entries, please use `clone`
  duped_target_hash = target_hash.dup

  source_hash.each do |k, v|
    unless duped_target_hash.key?(k)
      duped_target_hash[k] = v
      next
    end

    case v
      when Array
        missing_items_in_arr = find_missing_items_in_arr(duped_target_hash[k], v)
        if missing_items_in_arr.size > 0
          duped_target_hash[k] += missing_items_in_arr
        end
      when Hash
        duped_target_hash[k] = custom_merge(duped_target_hash[k], v)
      else
        # Nothing to do here
    end
  end

  duped_target_hash
end
```

**Usage**

```
one = {
  "endpoints"=>["get_route"],
  "features"=>["channel_selection"],
  "get_route"=> {
    "output"=> ["total_length", "seca_length"],
    "options"=> ["panama", "abcd"]
  }
}

other = {
  "endpoints"=>["get_route"],
  "features"=>["channel_selection"],
  "get_route"=> {
    "output"=> ["total_length", "seca_length"],
    "options"=> ["panama", "suez", "kiel"]
  }
}

rs_hash = custom_merge(other, one)

puts rs_hash
```

**Note**: Rails provides a [deep_merge](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_merge) but this can be used outside Rails. I have tested and it returns your desired output. Also it handles more nested entries like

```
one = {
  "endpoints"=>["get_route"],
  "features"=>["channel_selection"],
  "get_route"=> {
    "output"=> ["total_length", "seca_length"],
    "options"=> ["panama", "abcd"],

    "custom_options" => {
      "custom_output" => ["abc"],
      "custom_input" => ["xyz" ]
    }
  }
}

other = {
  "endpoints"=>["get_route"],
  "features"=>["channel_selection"],
  "get_route"=> {
    "output"=> ["total_length", "seca_length"],
    "options"=> ["panama", "suez", "kiel"],

    "custom_options" => {
      "custom_output" => ["abc", "def"]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much..made my day